# XSLT - Create Multiple Tables based on Child Node Value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is the source XML code:

```
<customers>
 <customer cid="c5391">
      <name>Evans, Terry</name>
      <street>641 Greenway Blvd.</street>
      <city>Mount Hope</city>
      <state>OH</state>
      <zip>44660</zip>
      <orders>
         <order oid="52517">
            <date>8/1/2017</date>
            <item iid="wb7133">
               <description>Insulated Water Bottle</description>
               <qty>2</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="gps1015">
               <description>Zendo GPS meter</description>
               <qty>1</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="bl2815">
               <description>Boot Laces (Medium)</description>
               <qty>1</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="tr8140">
               <description>Trail Mix (Pouch)</description>
               <qty>5</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="fa8442">
               <description>First Aid Kit (Pack Size)</description>
               <qty>1</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="bb7117">
               <description>Blister Patches</description>
               <qty>3</qty>
            </item>
         </order>
         <order oid="53003">
            <date>8/5/2017</date>
            <item iid="hp7814">
               <description>Fiberglass Light Hiking Poles (Spring Adj.)</description>
               <qty>1</qty>
            </item>
         </order>
         <order oid="54814">
            <date>8/6/2017</date>
            <item iid="sb6601">
               <description>Solar Battery Recharging Unit</description>
               <qty>1</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="br9002">
               <description>Bug Repellent (Deep Woodes)</description>
               <qty>2</qty>
            </item>
            <item iid="sb8502">
               <description>Sunblock SPF 30 (Hiking Size)</description>
               <qty>6</qty>
            </item>
         </order>
      </orders>
   </customer>
</customers>
```

I am trying to use XSL/HTML/CSS to reformat the code to look like below:
[image]

Here is my code, I am trying to create different order tables for each order (listed in descending order by order ID as shown in the sample photo above). Also, each order table should include the date of the order and the order ID:

```
    <table>
    
    <tr>
        <th>Item No.</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty</th>

    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="//order/item" group-by="date">
        <xsl:sort select="order/@oid" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@iid"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="description"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="qty"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
```

The result look like below.

[image]

Right now my code is returning all the items, but I need to create multiple tables based for each order, which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want a separate table for each date, or for each order. In your picture each table seems to have an order number, so it looks like it's the latter. Your items are already grouped by order, so it's not clear why you would need to do any grouping. Please provide an example with 3 orders, two of them on the same date, and add the **exact** result (as HTML code) you expect to get in the given example. Also clarify what is the date format used by the input, as that seems to be the major obstacle here.

Comment: One more thing: your question is tagged as `xslt-1.0`  yet your XSLT code has a `group-by` attribute which requires XSLT 2.0. Please verify which XSLT version is supported by your processor - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry for the confusion, I didn't know group-by requires XSLT 2.0...I am using XSLT 1.0, I will get rid of the group-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/customers">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="customer/orders/order">
                <!-- sort by date ??? -->
                <table border="1">
                    <!-- header -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                        </td>
                        <td/>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@oid"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item No.</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- body -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="item">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@iid"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="qty"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your XML example, this would produce:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>8/1/2017</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>52517</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Item No.</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>wb7133</td>
            <td>Insulated Water Bottle</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>gps1015</td>
            <td>Zendo GPS meter</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>bl2815</td>
            <td>Boot Laces (Medium)</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>tr8140</td>
            <td>Trail Mix (Pouch)</td>
            <td>5</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>fa8442</td>
            <td>First Aid Kit (Pack Size)</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>bb7117</td>
            <td>Blister Patches</td>
            <td>3</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>8/5/2017</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>53003</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Item No.</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>hp7814</td>
            <td>Fiberglass Light Hiking Poles (Spring Adj.)</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>8/6/2017</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>54814</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Item No.</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>sb6601</td>
            <td>Solar Battery Recharging Unit</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>br9002</td>
            <td>Bug Repellent (Deep Woodes)</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>sb8502</td>
            <td>Sunblock SPF 30 (Hiking Size)</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

which before adding any styling would render as:

[image]

I left out the sorting part, because (a) I don't know what is the date format of the input and (b) the orders seem to be already sorted by date anyway.

Comment: Hello. I edited my question with more detailed + the outputs when I run your code. I edited the XML a little bit too (customer is a child node of customers now). I don't know why, but when I run your code, the table is not showing up (forget about CSS formatting, the <table></table> isn't working, I just see the plain version of data itself (Updated in the question). Also, <xsl:value-of select="@oid"/> didn't work. Date is there, but not oid. But your answer definitely provided me some redirections! Thank you very much!

Comment: Pls ignore my previous comment! I know why the table and the oid failed to show up! It is because I didn't upload the completed version of XML, I forgot to include the <customer> node inside of the <customers> node

Comment: I have modified my answer to adapt it to your edited input.

Comment: P.S.  If you want the orders to appear in descending order by `oid` then replace the comment with  `<xsl:sort select="@oid" data-type="number" order="descending"/>`.

Comment: Thank you so very much!! It worked! <xsl:template match="/customers"> and <xsl:for-each select="customer/orders/order"> were the two parts really  confused me a lot yesterday because I wasn't sure what to select. Thank you!